# .epub file in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

Can any one suggest me a way, to load the data from a .epub file in SSIS or any other way??

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with SSIS.

epub files are zipped, so you need an uncompress task that writes to working directory.

Following that, the files are either XML or xHTML and can be processed very easily with XML tasks.

I'm not sure about DRM issues though.

Comment: all i could find in the zip  file is .epub file....there was no XML file or xHTML file

Comment: Open the .epub file with winzip or similar, or rename it to .zip and then open it.